# app remotely control presentation from iPhone

Tags: iphone, controls

I'm trying to build a simple app similar to [the "Remote" app](http://www.apple.com/itunes/remote/). Basically, it can connect via WiFi to a Mac and controls the presentation (MS Powerpoint 2008) on it, like going to the next or the previous slide. Also, there would be a "server" running on the Mac that can talk to the iPhone app, which acts as client. Can anyone give me some pointers on how the client and server may be built? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is way too broad. It sounds like you want other people to do your work for you....

Comment: did you achieve your goal ? I also was looking such functionality. Can you help me out if you had any luck ?

Comment: I managed to use raw socket to send command to Mac, which then in turn parses and executes it.